# Creating recourses from the Azure DevOps Automation using Terraform vs PowerShell

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

I am learning azure devops CI/CD pipeline. I am looking at the example where it shows how to use the terraform to create resources in Azure through automation.
My question is why we would need Terraform or ARM templates when we can create the Azure resources from PowerShell or Azure CLI?  I mean we are able to execute Powershell from Yaml so why not just use PowerShell.

Note: My question many not make sense but I am asking a question for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Terraform stores data in plain text in the state file. At any point, any changes need to be implemented. We can recreate the entire infrastructure in minutes using state files. The only difference between it and ARM is that ARM lacks a statefile mechanism. If your use case involves securing your configuration files, you might choose ARM templates over Terraform.
CLI is a cross-platform command-line tool used to **connect** and execute **commands on Azure resources**.

Here is the reference  [tutorials](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/terraform/)
[DevOps Pipelines](https://purple.telstra.com/blog/terraform-with-azure-devops-pipeline)